# Lagrange Multiplicator: find minima and maxima

Tags: systems-of-equations, lagrange-multiplier, maxima-minima

I've the following function:
$$ f(x,y) = (x+1)^2 e^y $$
with the additional condition
$$ 2(x-1)^2 + y^2 = 3 $$

What I've done so far: I constructed one single function:
$$ L(x, y, \lambda) = (x+1)^2 e^y + \lambda(2(x-1)^2+y^2-3)$$

Then, I calculated the derivations:
$$ \frac{d}{dx} = 4 \lambda (x-1)+2(x+1)e^y $$
$$ \frac{d}{dy} = 2 \lambda y + (x+1)^2 e^y $$
$$ \frac{d}{d \lambda} = 2(x-1)^2+y^2-3  $$

Now I should solve the system of equations, don't I ? But how? How would you proceed? I thought that I should solve the system for a certain variable, but I'm really not sure...so I'd be thankful if anybody could help! :)

Comment: These derivates are all put equal to 0. Solving a Lagrange system is, in general, pretty tricky if it is possible at all. There is no algorithm, you just do what you can with what is usually a system of nonlinear equations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You equate all these derivatives to $0$. So you get:
$$4 \lambda (x-1)+2(x+1)e^y=0\tag{1}$$
$$2 \lambda y + (x+1)^2 e^y=0 \tag{2}$$
$$2(x-1)^2+y^2-3=0\tag{3}$$
From $2$, we have $(x+1) e^y=\frac{-2\lambda y}{x+1}$.

Substitute this in $1$ to get $y=x^2-1$.

Substitute this in $3$ to get $x^4=4x\Rightarrow x=0,4^{\frac{1}{3}}$. Using this we get the possible pairs $\left( x,y\right)$ as $\left( 0,-1\right)$ and $\left( 4^{\frac{1}{3}},4^{\frac{2}{3}}-1\right)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot Prathyush! I've 2 questions remaining: 
1) Why x = 4? Isn't it x = 2^(2/3) ? The first solution x=0 is clear!
2) How did you get the idea to start with (2)? Trying, or is there any "system"?

Comment: @DMan 1)Sorry yeah, youre right. It was a silly calculation error. 2) What I did is tried to find similar terms, which I could eliminate. For ex, $e^y$in $1$ is a very difficult term to deal with, so I tried to eliminate it using $2$ which then led to the rest of the solution automatically. It'll come with lots of practice

Comment: All right thanks a lot for the correction and your comment. In that case I've to do a lot of more practice...
So, the min is at (0,-1) and the max at the second point =)